# Zoho People API Today Birthday

Tags: api, zoho

I'm using ["Search Records based on record values"](https://www.zoho.com/people/help/api/fetch-record-api.html#6) People Zoho API in order to get the list of the users that have a birthday today.

> Purpose: This API is used to fetch all the records of a form based on
>   the record values.
>
> Request URL:
>   https://people.zoho.com/people/api/forms//getRecords?authtoken=****&searchParams={searchField:
>   '', searchOperator: '', searchText :
>   ''}

but none of the operators allow me to search for `Date_of_birth` in "like" mode. For example:

```
https://people.zoho.com/people/api/forms/employee/getRecords?authtoken=c****&searchParams={searchField : 'Date_of_birth', searchOperator : 'Starts_With', searchText : '2-Jul'}
```

will return error:

> The search operator 'Starts_With' is invalid for the search field 'Date_of_birth'

and other date operators, not allowing to get a list of records that have a birthday in the specified date.

1. Am I using the correct method and what are the proper parameters?
2. If I'm using the incorrect method, what is the correct one and proper parameters to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The received official answer from Zoho support states such functionality doesn't exist in Zoho API. Hence it's not possible to get a list of employees who have a birthday today:

> Hello Oleg, 
>   Greetings from Zoho people! 
>   With regards to your query, 
>   As of now, we do not have any options to fetch the employee whose birthday falls today through API. If he wants to be notified when the employee has their birthday, we can set the mail alert via workflows.
>   Have a great day !

Answer (score -2):

An API that can fetch users whose data attributes has been modified in Zoho people.
(E.g.  Any users whose any attribute is modified at Zoho end in last 24hrs should only be captured by API )